# Controlar visualizações diárias de imagem

Tags: banco-de-dados, imagem, script, cookies, anúncio

> Não quero o script pronto, apenas saber a melhor estratégia.

Pessoal, estou com uma dificuldade em descobrir qual a melhor forma de controlar a quantidade de visualizações diárias de um banner.

Por exemplo:
Tenho um BD com 500 banners (nome, link, imagem, dias q vai aparecer) mas em cada página do site só mostram 7 banners de cada vez.

Como fazer para que:

- Todos os banners fossem vistos a mesma quantidade de vezes;
- Só repetir um banner após todos os outros terem sido mostrados;
- Não usasse visualizações aleatórias

Cada banner aparecerá certa quantidade de dias e depois será apagado.

A pergunta é como fazer isso funcionar!!!!
Será q é melhor fazer via cookie, via script no BD, qual a melhor forma?

Comment: Não usar "visualizações aleatórias" significa que os banners devem aparecer numa ordem específica?

Answer (score 0):

> [Como fazer para que] Todos os banners fossem vistos a mesma quantidade de vezes;

Isso só seria possível se houvesse um número de visualizações de banners múltiplo da quantidade total de banners, o que não é prático na realidade. Estou interpretando isso como "as visualizações de banners devem ser distribuídas de forma equilibrada".

Pra resolver isso, basicamente você cria uma tabela temporária que armazena as views diárias de cada banner. Daí você vai incrementando, nessa tabela temporária, um contador a cada requisição dessa imagem. Na próxima requisição de banner, você pega o que tiver menos views. Isso garante o equilíbrio na distribuição.

Para remover os banners expirados, verifique no começo de cada dia se ele ainda é válido.

---

Detalhando um pouco mais:

Você pode deixar a sua estrutura no DB mais ou menos assim:

```
banner

| id | nome | link | imagem |     inicio | dias | ativo |
|----+------+------+--------+------------+------+-------|
|  0 | ...  | ...  | ...    | 2017-01-28 |   10 |     1 |
|  1 | ...  | ...  | ...    | 2017-01-31 |    3 |     0 |
|  2 | ...  | ...  | ...    | 2017-02-02 |   20 |     1 |


views_banner

| id | hoje |
|----+------|
|  0 |    3 |
|  2 |    2 |
```

Para o mecanismo que desativa os banners expirados, você pode programar um script para rodar todo dia à meia noite no servidor (cron no Linux, Agendador de Tarefas no Windows ou um evento no próprio banco de dados). Ele vai fazer o seguinte em cada uma das linhas da tabela banner que estiverem ativas:

1. Seja `data_final` a data de `inicio` acrescida do valor de `dias`;
2. Se `data_final` for mais antiga que a data atual, desativa o banner (ativo=0).

Além disso, para o mecanismo de distribuição, faça o seguinte no mesmo script diário:

1. Remova todos os registros em `views_banner`;
2. Insira todos os ids de banners ativos em `views_banner` com a coluna `hoje=0` (essa coluna representa as visualizações que o banner teve no dia).

Ao receber uma requisição em http://site.com/banner_rotativo, faça o seguinte com a tecnologia server-side de sua preferência:

1. Selecione algum registro que tenha o menor valor na coluna `hoje` (falta regra pra resolver empates);
2. Incremente o valor `hoje` desse registro;
3. Retorne a imagem referente a esse banner.

Comment: Há alguma maneira de se atualizar o valor de *dias*  do registro original ao fazer o select? Algo como `select id, link, dias = dias - 1 from banners`, mas que esse decremento em dias fosse armazenado no banco.

Comment: Com `SELECT` não é possível, pois essa declaração é para recuperar dados, e não para alterá-los. Use `UPDATE` para decrementar. Mas na lógica da minha resposta, você não deve decrementar a coluna `dias`. Apenas some os dias à data inicial para ver se ele ainda é válido.